# How to invoke anonymous inner classes's methods?

Tags: java, inner-classes, anonymous-inner-class

I understand this code is not legal:

```
class Popcorn {
    public void pop() {
        System.out.println("popcorn");
    }
}

class Food {
    Popcorn p = new Popcorn() {
        public void sizzle() {
            System.out.println("anonymous sizzling popcorn");
        }
        public void pop() {
            System.out.println("anonymous popcorn");
        }
    };
    public void popIt() {
        p.pop(); // OK, Popcorn has a pop() method
        p.sizzle(); // Not Legal! Popcorn does not have sizzle()
    }
}
```

What then is a way to invoke the sizzle method at all?

Comment: add sizzle to Popcorn, no otherway

Comment: My initial reaction is to ask why you would *achieve* by adding an extra public method to an anonymous class.

Comment: `new Popcorn() { ... }.sizzle();`

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline That was what I was looking for. Since if you can't invoke the method it's a bad example and it's from the official OCJP study guide by Kathy bates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The anonymous class's method must override/implement a method of its superclass to be accessible from the outside. There is no way around writing more boilerplate to achieve your goal, unfortunately.

Comment: +1 The only alternative is to use reflection which I would only suggest if you can't fix the code.